# iOS notifications registration not asking for permission and not registering in some devices

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I created a provisioning profile for my app id and enabled push notifications, I also refreshed the profile in Xcode. In my `AppDelegate` I call

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];`

The issue is that the application is not asking for the permission to register for push notifications. Regardless, in some devices it is registering properly and I can see the token in my server, but in other devices this is failing for some reason and no token is obtained.

My provisioning profile also contains

```
<key>aps-environment</key>
<string>production</string>
```

I am quite sure there is a relationship between the application not asking for permission and the fact that some devices won't register properly for push.

Any ideas on what could be going on here or how to troubleshoot it without actually debugging?

Edit: I also found that on one device the app registers successfully and gets the token but it won't appear under the notification center (either in include or in not include).

Comment: Have you by any chance selected "Don't allow" even once on the devices when a prompt appeared? The app won't ask you every time (even if you do a fresh install). Does the registration fail with any errors?

Comment: No, even on first time install it won't ask for permission yet in some devices it will register properly. On other devices it won't get a token, but won't also enter the fail registration method.

Comment: have you enabled `remote notification` option from xcode?

Comment: @Virussmca I am not sure I get you, where is that option located?